# mount a folder from one server to another

Tags: linux, mount, cloud

I'm using cloud. I want to mount a folder in the cloudstack management server to the system where xenserver is installed. But while doing it, error occurred. I have done so many things but error exist.

```
[root@xenserver2 ~]# mount -t nfs 10.176.14.26:/mnt/secondary /secondarymount
mount: 10.176.14.26:/mnt/secondary failed, reason given by server: Permission denied
```

10.176.14.26 is the management server ip.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Error log says...?

Comment: What is the output of `showmount -e 10.176.14.26` in xenserver2 machine

Comment: Do you have permission to the remote folder? You can try adding `-o username=myusername,password=mypassword` to the mount command

Comment: @max this is the output [root@xenserver2 ~]# showmount -e 10.176.14.26
     Export list for 10.176.14.26:
     /export *
     [root@xenserver2 ~]#

Comment: @Nick van Tilborg the following is the output i got: [root@xenserver2 ~]# mount -t nfs 10.176.14.26:/mnt/secondary /secondarymount-o username=root,password=********
Usage: mount -V                 : print version
       mount -h                 : print this help

Comment: It looks like you did something wrong with the parameters: `/secondarymount-o`. It must be with a space between the parameters: 
`/secondarymount -o`

Answer (score 1):

Your `showmount -e 10.176.14.26` output shows that you exported `/export` directory

but you are trying to mount /mnt/secondary diectory !!!

Please update your Question with this detail

What you exported in `/etc/export` file ?

**Example**

In Server Side

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/exports
/export   10.10.1.2(rw,sync)
```

Start `rpcbibd` and `nfs` services

```
[root@localhost mnt]# service rpcbind restart
Stopping rpcbind:                                          [  OK  ]
Starting rpcbind:                                          [  OK  ]
```

```
[root@localhost mnt]# service nfs restart
Shutting down NFS mountd:                                  [  OK  ]
Shutting down NFS daemon:                                  [  OK  ]
Shutting down NFS quotas:                                  [  OK  ]
Shutting down NFS services:                                [  OK  ]
Starting NFS services:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting NFS quotas:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS daemon:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS mountd:
```

```
[root@localhost ~]# iptables -F
```

**Flushing iptables is not the correct way configure a proper iptables rule**

In Client Side check exported directory

```
[root@localhost ~]# showmount -e 10.10.1.1
Export list for 10.10.1.1:
/export 10.10.1.2
```

```
[root@localhost ~]# mount -t nfs 10.10.1.1:/export/ /mnt/
[root@localhost ~]#
```